# AD login gives a token, but API returns 401

Tags: c#, directory, azure-ad-b2c

We have an azure b2c instance, and I registered postman as an app.

I then went into the API app registration's manifest and added this:

```
{
            "allowedMemberTypes": [
                "Application"
            ],
            "description": "Accesses the TodoListService-Cert as an application.",
            "displayName": "access_as_application",
            "id": "8be4aa9a-8ec7-4443-a74f-c3545bfceee5",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "lang": null,
            "origin": "Application",
            "value": "access_as_application"
}
```

On the Postman app registration I then gave it the access_as_application permission like so:
[image]

Now we have the following problem, in postman I select client credential flow and added the info provided by AD.
Including setting scope to : https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

When I do a 'Get New Access Token' postman succesfully receives a token, but when I add the token as a bearer and call the API through postman, we get a 401 and it shows `Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"`

Any ideas what i could have missed?

Comment: If you decode your token at jwt.ms does it contain the expected scope(s)?

Comment: Hmmm, doesnt look like it has any scopes in the decoded token

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your application ID for the scope.
Setting it to `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` gives you an MS Graph API token.

Set it to e.g. (replace application-id with your app client id)

```
<application id>/.default
```

Comment: So I Tried this and same thing :(

Comment: Can you inspect the token you get with https://jwt.ms? It should contain your API's application ID or app ID URI in the "aud" claim.